# Need image height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want the left side background will take equal height of right section area.I tried to solve this problem in many ways using padding,height.But when i resize the screen it don't remain fit.
[image: Problem]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="s3-left col-sm-8">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo4.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive center-block"/></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.s3-left {
    background: url("images/background2.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 / 100% 100%;    
}
.s3-left img {
    width: 92px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working example using Embeded StackOverflow Snippet or at best JSFiddle (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it? It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without being able to see your code.

Comment: I am not friendly with online code editor.You can go to this link for more details. [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017710/background-image-is-creating-unnecessary-gap-at-different-screen-size-in-differe)

Comment: it would be helpful if you uploaded the photos (individually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex box setting `display: flex` to equal the height of both areas and set `background: cover` to `.s3-left`

```css
.section-three .s3-left.col-sm-8 {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.my-container{  /*added this class to div.row*/
  display: flex;    /*used to equal the height of both areas*/
}
.s3-left {
  background: url("http://lsst.astro.washington.edu/intro/imsim/images/ImageSimNoBackgroundSmall.png");
  background-size: cover;   /*using cover to fit all area*/
}
.s3-left img {
  width: 92px;
  padding: 199px 0;
}
.s3-image img {
  width: 100%;
}
.s3-logo {
  padding: 48px 0 25px;
}
.s3-heading h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}
.s3-description .gap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.s3-description p {
  font-size: 12.4px;
  padding-bottom: 58px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section-three">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row my-container">  <!--added the class my-container-->
            <!---------------------- Left-Area ------------------->
            <div class="s3-left col-sm-8">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="logo" class="img-responsive center-block"/></a>
            </div>
            <!-----------------------Right-Area ------------------->
            <div class="s3-right col-sm-4">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="s3-right-up row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="s3-logo row">
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="logo" class="img-responsive center-block" style="width:32px; height:auto;"/>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="s3-heading row">
                                <h5 class="text-uppercase text-center"> Vintage oliva </h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="s3-description row">
                                <div class="gap">
                                    <p class="text-justify">
                                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="s3-right-down row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="s3-image row">
                                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="logo" class="img-responsive"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Check it in Full Page**

[Check this for more info about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background)

Comment: Thanks.Thanks a lot.I tried it in many ways unlimited times......But failed.Now problem solved by you.Thanks for your help...:) @Yandy_Viera